# Issue when asserting either of 2 response codes in Postman - pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200,409]);

Tags: javascript, postman

I have some Postman tests using this assertion to check any of these 2 response codes 200 or 409

```html
pm.test("Successful claim lodgement?", function () {
       
       pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([200,409]);
       
      
    });
```

however when I run the Postman tests via Newman or Jenkins, my assertion fails when I get a valid code response 409.
MRJ - Claim (fire)
POST https://sandbox-api.iag.com.au/services/v1/digitalclaims/nrma/lodgeClaim [409 Conflict, 536B, 1462ms]

The error shown in the console is:

```
**expected response code to not be 4XX or 5XX**
```

Why is the assertion failing if the response is 409 valid??? The assertion seems validating "not to be"

Comment: How are you using the Collection in Jenkins? Via a link or exporting the file?

Comment: exportin file, the assertino errors also appears when running locally using Postman runner and Newman

AssertionError: expected response code to not be 4XX or 5XX